# Breaking apart a string in C# for a calculator

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

I am creating a simple calculator in ASP.NET.  When the user selects a button, the value gets added to a single textBox.  Once the equal button is selected, the string is to be sent to the ASP.NET server (im using c# code behind file).  The c# code behind is suppose to break apart this string, calculate a value, and return the value to the same text box.  I am using a class called calculation that has an add,subtract,multiply, and divide methods (its a requirement).

I am having trouble determining the best way to break apart the entire string like 3*4/65+1 for example.

I am not sure what the best way is to accomplish this.  below is the code i have in my c# file although it is not much.  I appreciate any help / tips.

```
  using System; 
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Web;
  using System.Web.UI;
  using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

   public partial class Assign2_Calc : System.Web.UI.Page
  {
    protected void ButtonEqual_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    string inputStr = inputBox.Text;
    double result = 0;;
    Calculator myCalculator = new Calculator();
    switch ()
    {
        case "+":
            result = myCalculator.Add(val1, val2);
            break;
    }


    inputBox.Text = result.ToString();
    }  
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [`Regex.Split()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ze12yx1d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with capturing parentheses in the regular expression so as to return both the operators and the arguments of the expression, e.g.:

```
Regex.Split("([+-/*()])")
```

Using the example expression: `3*4/65+1`, the result would be: `{"3","*","4","/","65","+","1"}`

Using an expression with an unimplemented operator: `3*2^2/65+1`, the result would be: `{"3","*","2^2","/","65","+","1"}`.

You would get an array of strings hopefully containing separate arguments and operators.  You would have to check for invalid elements in each string, such as an unimplemented operator or other invalid character (e.g. `^`, `\`).  Should any string in the split array not be only a valid argument or an operator, you would return an error result.

Comment: What would this approach, for ex, return for `6+4/2`? 5 or 8?

Comment: L.B, for `6+4/2` you'd get an array: `{"6","+","4","/","2"}`.  From there it would be necessary to apply operator precedence and calculate the results.

Comment: and for `6+(4/2`? (No closing paranthesis) or `6+4)/2`

Comment: For `6+(4/2` with `Regex.Split("([+-/*])")`, you'd get `{"6","+","(4","/","2"}`, which is obviously invalid. You'd have to expand your `Split` regex to include parentheses to deal with this: `Regex.Split("([+-/*()])")` would give `{"6","+","(","4","/","2"}`, and then check for matching parenthesis pairs.

Comment: So Now you say you have posted a good answer? I am waiting for an answer to cover these issues. (if it so simple, post a working code please)

Comment: L.B, the question was "I am having trouble determining the best way to break apart the entire string like 3*4/65+1 for example".  At the moment I'm writing this, the other two answers are answering "How to calculate a string expression", which isn't the question.  AFAIK, the asker needs to write his own calculation code, not use someone else's.  It may or may not be the best approach to the whole problem, but we aren't being asked to answer that.

Comment: In fact, you are right about the question although this wouldn't solve his problem.

Comment: L.B, No, it wouldn't solve his entire problem, but *we weren't asked to do that*.  For whatever reason, this is what we were asked.  Without more information, we can't know *why* the question was asked in this way, and those answering shouldn't make potentially invalid assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

For simple expressions you could use the [`Compute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute.aspx) method:

```
var result = new DataTable().Compute("3 * 4 / 65 + 1", null);
```

There are also third party libraries such as [`NCalc`](http://ncalc.codeplex.com/) which you might find useful.

Comment: Nice :), but the user ask for his homework, just throw some code that not work and have no sense... and wait to solve it - to make the parse part of code.

Comment: The question was for tips on how to split an expression string.  This just gives the result, which wasn't the question.

Comment: Since when providing the end result and the precise way to achieve this end result is considered wrong on SO? I thought that the end goal was to evaluate the expression, which is what I provided an answer for. The part in the question about breaking the string might simply be due to the OPs lack of knowledge of the built-in methods in the framework that would allow him writing error prone code and wheel reinvention. Of course if you want to reinvent the wheel feel free to provide an answer to what you think the question is here.

Comment: I agree that the specifics of the question may be motivated by lack of knowledge, but I've been in the same situation as this, and have decided to use my own code due to the limitations of the built-in .NET methods.  We shouldn't make these sort of assumptions.  As someone who has been in this position as an asker, it's very frustrating to receive an answer that tries to solve the whole problem in a way that I've already rejected rather than to just answer the question I asked.